# Redirecting and executing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http

I was wondering if it is possible to create a website in which pressing a botton, it redirects you to another and executes a piece of javascript. All should be triggered by the same button.

Here an example:

- I enter into a website and press a button
- It redirects me to my gmail and presses mark all read.

*All come from the button of the first page.

Is any way to do this? Maybe not with javascript but simulating pressing the mark all read button with the HTTP request of the gmail website or something like this.

Thanks

EDIT: I had another idea... could I get the html code making a request with the button and then try to call the javascript function of the mark read button?

Comment: You do realise this would be a huge safety risk if it were possible, right?

Comment: This would class as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS for short), and is a definite no. If it did work, Google would patch it almost immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you control both websites, the one with the button and the one to which the user is redirected, you can arrange it so that something in a session cookie, or an extra parameter in the redirect, indicates that the user wants an extra piece of javascript to be executed at the destination site. The destination site would check for the cookie value or GET parameter and execute the additional action based on that.

Of course you do want to be careful the security issues, and if you don't control the destination page, I don't think you'll find a workable solution.

Comment: Can you check my edit? I think it has to be possible some way.

Comment: If you're talking about actually manipulating the gmail site I don't think it has to be possible at all. If it were, you could just as easily mislabel the button and delete the user's emails, or forward them all to yourself, or compose and send more emails from their account. So to prevent that, gmail has every reason to make this difficult to accomplish. I hope they make it impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible from pure JavaScript running in the browser.

You could create a browser plugin (like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)) to do something similar. That plugin would have to be installed on the users' browser.